# com.install4j.runtime.launcher crashing executable upon startup - Mac

Tags: macos, crash, startup, launch

I am having an unusual executable issue whenever I start up my Mac. The program is labelled "com.install4j.runtime.launcher". I assume it is related to [this site](http://www.ej-technologies.com) but I am not sure if this is part of a system update or a third party application that requires this "4J launcher". Either way it has been bugging me for weeks now and I am not sure how to get rid of it!
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I employed some help from a colleague to understand this. It turned out to be a simple and slightly embarrassing solution. Somewhere down the line I must have installed this 4J executable and for some reason it was set to open on start-up (not sure if this was a fault of my own or the Mac's).

For anyone else who has an issue with unwanted applications starting up upon log in, you can solve them fairly easily by hitting:

Apple icon (Top left) -> System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items

Then simply hit minus (-) to be rid of them! You may find some more unwanted applications on there like iTunes Helper or (in my instance) Flu.x which was being loaded 4 times... A nice way to speed up the mac on start up as well.

Hope this helps anyone who has similar problems.